# Contact form in SiteFinity C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, sitefinity

I want to do basic functionality with a simple contact form and on submit the form emails to someone. This is quite easy to do in asp.net, however I am having trouble once I upload it as a user control. Do you have a good example I can look at? Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

It is the same as you would have in a normal asp.net page, the sample assumes you are using the latest version of Sitefinity and that you are have a RadScriptManager or ScriptManager on your master page.

Firstly here is my example form codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class UserControls_LandingPage_contactForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool bSent = false;
        try
        {
            //create the email and add the settings
            var email = new MailMessage();
            email.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail);
            email.To.Add(new MailAddress(FromEmail));
            email.Subject = Subject;
            email.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //build the body
            var sBody = new StringBuilder();
            sBody.Append("<strong>Contact Details</strong><br /><br />");
            sBody.AppendFormat("Needs: {0}<br />", cboConsultationType.SelectedValue);
            sBody.AppendFormat("Name: {0}<br />", txtName.Text);
            sBody.AppendFormat("Email: {0}<br />", txtEmail.Text);
            sBody.AppendFormat("Number: {0}<br />", txtPhone.Text);
            sBody.AppendFormat("Comment: {0}<br />", txtMsg.Text);
            email.Body = sBody.ToString();

            //send the email
            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            smtpServer.Send(email);

            //mark as sent ok
            bSent = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //send any errors back
            //add your own custom handling of errors;
        }

        //let the end user know if it was a success
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + (bSent ? SuccessText : FailureText) + "');", true);
    }

    //properties    
    public string FromEmail
    {
        get { return _fromEmail; }
        set { _fromEmail = value; }
    }
    public string Subject
    {
        get { return _subject; }
        set { _subject = value; }
    }
    public string SuccessText
    {
        get { return _successText; }
        set { _successText = value; }
    }
    public string FailureText
    {
        get { return _failureText; }
        set { _failureText = value; }
    }

    //fields
    private string _fromEmail = "info@example.com.au";
    private string _subject = "Website Enquiry";
    private string _successText = "Thank you for submitting your details we will be in touch shortly.";
    private string _failureText = "There was a problem submitting your details please try again shortly.";

}
```

ASCX Code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactForm.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_LandingPage_contactForm" %>
<fieldset>
    <div class="focus">
        <label>
            I need...</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboConsultationType" runat="server" CssClass="select sub web">
            <asp:ListItem Value="I Need A New Web Site">A completely new website</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Web Site Upgrade">My website upgraded</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Application Design">An application </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="An ecommerce website">New Ecommerce website</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="lblName" AssociatedControlID="txtName" runat="server"
                Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
                ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Name is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPhone" EnableViewState="false"
                Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorPhone" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
                ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Phone is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" EnableViewState="false"
                Text="Email"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Email is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" ErrorMessage="Email address is invalid">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtMsg" EnableViewState="false"
                Text="How can we assist you?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Wrap="true"></asp:TextBox>
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="submit"
                Text="Send" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Then the only other items you need to be wary of is in the web.config you need to modify the system.net settings for email:

```
 <system.net>
 <mailSettings>
   <smtp from="mailmaster@yourdomain.com">
     <network host="smtp.yourdomain.com" userName="Your_Username" password="Your_Password" port="25" />
   </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then upload the control or modify your web.config .  Then provided your SMTP server is all set up correctly the form should send no problem.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: No problem I think you have to mark mine as the answer, provided of course you think it was right ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think one good approach is using the incorporated mail sender. The profits are that you can configure the settings inside the Administration->Settings->Advanced->System->SMTP

```
            var smtpSettings = Config.Get<SystemConfig>().SmtpSettings;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();                

            message.From = new MailAddress(smtpSettings.UserName);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat(body);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = sb.ToString();
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            EmailSender.Get().Send(message);
```

You can use notifications too.